# Create msi which does not require admin privileges Visual Studio 2017 Setup Project

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

I know there are existing answers out there, but they are possibly dated.  It seems that Microsoft has made many changes in this area over the past 6-8 years.

Basically, I want to deploy my application and all of its dependencies in a msi that end-users can install without admin privileges on their machine.  I've carefully chosen file locations that are writable by joe user and only have a handful of registry keys in HKCU.  The "current user only" install is selected as well.  I've even set up a test project which only installs a single text file and still, the admin prompt appeared.

I am mostly "a linux guy", but it seems strange to me that if a piece of software does not require admin privileges for installation then it would be in everyone's best interest not to give it to it.